# how to add to layout dynamically with multiple RelativeLayout.LayoutParams

Tags: android, listview, android-relativelayout

In my fragment, I want each custom item in my listview to look as follows:

Name

SetsXReps

[][][][][] ---> array of textviews

[][][][][] ---> array of checkboxes

The number of textviews and checkboxes depends upon the item in the adapter, so I need to create that part dynamically. I am having trouble adding these elements dynamically to my relativelayout that I partially define in my xml. Here is my fragment class followed by my xml for the custom list item. The id for the layout is list_item_exercise_in_workout. I have the code to add the row of textviews, but am running into trouble adding the checkboxes. I have commented below the code that I have tried adding but is not working. The issue is coming from the second RelativeLayout.LayoutParams and how I attempt to add the second row to the view. Thanks in advance, I really appreciate any help that is given to me.

```
 public class WorkoutFragment extends Fragment
{
    public static final String EXTRA_ALREADYCREATED_ID = "alreadyCreated";

    private ExAdapter adapter;
    private ListView listView;
    private ArrayList<Set> sets;
    private Workout w;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        UUID workoutId = (UUID) getArguments().getSerializable(EXTRA_ALREADYCREATED_ID);
        w = WorkoutMASTER.get(getActivity()).getWorkout(workoutId);
        sets = w.getSets();
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent,Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_workout, parent, false);
        listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listWorkout);

        adapter = new ExAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.fragment_workout, R.id.listWorkout, sets);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        return v;
    }
    public static WorkoutFragment newInstance(UUID workoutId)
    {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable(EXTRA_ALREADYCREATED_ID, workoutId);
        WorkoutFragment fragment = new WorkoutFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        return fragment;
    }
    private class ExAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Set>
    {
        public ExAdapter(Context c, int resource, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Set> sets ) {
            super(c, 0, sets);
        }
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            //if we werent given a view, inflate one
            if(convertView == null)
            {
                convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item_exercise_in_workout, null);
            }
            Set s = getItem(position);

            RelativeLayout container = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayoutEx);

           TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.exName);
            name.setText(s.getName());
            TextView setsReps = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.setsXreps);
            setsReps.setText(s.getSets() + "X" + s.getReps());

            CheckBox[] checkBoxes = new CheckBox[s.getSetsInt()];
            EditText[] weightBoxes = new EditText[s.getSetsInt()];
            //initialize weightBoxes's text to the inputted weight
            for(int i = 0; i < weightBoxes.length+1; i++)
            {
                weightBoxes[i] = new EditText(getActivity());
                weightBoxes[i].setText(s.getWeight());
                weightBoxes[i].setId(i);

                checkBoxes[i] = new CheckBox(getActivity());

                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                //statement here to add the edit text's horizontally
                if(i==0)
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
                else
                 params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, i-1);

                params.leftMargin = 107;

                //params2.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, i);
                //params2.leftMargin = 107;

                container.addView(weightBoxes[i], params);
                //container.addView(checkBoxes[i], params2);
            }
            return convertView;
        }
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutEx"
   >
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Name"
    android:id="@+id/exName"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="SetsXReps"
    android:id="@+id/setsXreps"
    android:layout_below="@id/exName"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
   />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/setsXreps"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="112dp" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually give a `ListView` a number of custom layouts, so that you don't have to add them dynamically.

To do this, you need to override your adapter's `getItemViewType` and `getViewTypeCount` method.

`getViewTypeCount` simply needs to return an integer == the number of different layouts you will have.

`getItemViewType` takes a position, and you can then evaluate the item at that position and return a different `int` depending on the object type or whatever parameters you need to evaluate.

Then, in `getView`, you can call `getItemViewType` for that position, create a switch or if block to load the appropriate view type, and then voila, you have different xml layouts, rather than trying to build them all individually.